# Nesting queries in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm trying to figure out if there is an easy way to nest a query in Graphql. I have two tables, one with the beach records and one with the definitions of the conditions.

What i'm trying to return is the conditionName and conditionDescription if the surfCondition matches (surfCondition = 2}

```
query MyQuery {
  lifeguard {
    beachID
    id
    surfCondition (match the second query)
        conditionName (display)
        conditionDescription (display)
    updated_at
    created_at
  }

  lifeguard_conditions {
    surfCondition
    conditionName
    conditionDescription
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally this would be handled on the GraphQL server to accept a filter.
So, for example, you can pass a variable to `surfCondition` such as

```
surfCondition(filter: 2)
```

…which would then return automatically the filtered data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).